# Why does Moose make_immutable kill this script?

Tags: perl, immutability, moose

```
package testDB;
use Moose;
use Carp;
use SQL::Library;

has 'lib' => (#FOLDBEG
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
    default => 'default',
    trigger => \&_sql_lib_builder,
);#FOLDEND

has 'lib_dir' => (#FOLDBEG
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'Str',
    default => '/SQL',
);#FOLDEND

has '_sql_lib' => (#FOLDBEG                                                                                                                            
   builder => '_sql_lib_builder',
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Str',
);

has '_sql_lib' => (#FOLDBEG                                                                                                                            
    builder => '_sql_lib_builder',
    is => 'rw',
           handles => {
        get_sql => 'retr',
        get_elements => 'elements',
    },
);

sub _sql_lib_builder {
    my ($self, $lib) = shift();
    $self->lib() or die("I am unable to get a lib.");
    $lib = $self->lib unless $lib;


    my $lib_dir = $self->lib_dir;
    print $lib_dir."\n";

    my $lib_file = $lib_dir . '/' . $lib . '.sql';

    unless (-e $lib_file ) {
        confess "SQL library $lib does not exist";
    }

    my $library = new SQL::Library { lib => $lib_file };

    $self->_sql_lib($library);

}#FOLDEND

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

my $tdb=testDB->new();
```

Using perl 5.8.8 and Moose 2.0205

```
$ perl testDB.pl 
I am unable to get a lib. at testDB.pl line 35.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the `_sql_lib` attribute twice, once saying `isa Str` and once saying it handles methods (which a `Str` doesn't), but that's not the problem you're talking about.

The main problem is that you didn't define `_sql_lib` with `lazy => 1`.  Any attribute whose builder (or `default`) depends on other attributes of the object must be `lazy`, because Moose doesn't guarantee the order in which attributes are assigned values during object construction.

```
# REMOVE THIS:
#has '_sql_lib' => (#FOLDBEG                                 
#   builder => '_sql_lib_builder',
#    is => 'rw',
#    isa => 'Str',
#);

has '_sql_lib' => (#FOLDBEG                                 
    builder => '_sql_lib_builder',
    is => 'rw',
    lazy => 1,                       # ADD THIS LINE
    handles => {
        get_sql => 'retr',
        get_elements => 'elements',
    },
);
```

The reason that `make_immutable` brings out the bug is that calling it generates a different constructor for your class, which happens to initialize the attributes in a different order.

Comment: oops the other '_sql_lib' was a debugging error. your lazy=>1 fix does the trick. thanks!